# How to use tabs in an ActiveAdmin edit form rendered from an ERB partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

I had to change an ActiveAdmin edit form from that I've been using to an ERB partial due to several technical reasons.

The form is quite massive and I had to split it into tabs already. When attempting to add tabs by using `<% tabs do %>` in the ERB partial, the following error appears in the `rails server` output:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 209ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `tabs' for #<#<Class:0x007fb1827cdbf8>:0x007fb181b16d60>):
    1: <%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @consignment], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder, html: { enctype: 'multipart/form-data' } do |f| %>
    2:   <% f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys %>
    3:   
    4:   <% tabs do %>
    5:   
    6:     <% tab 'Foo' do %>
    7:   
  app/views/admin/consignments/_form.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_admin_consignments__form_erb__783297827544755550_70200180247600'
  app/views/admin/consignments/_form.erb:1:in `_app_views_admin_consignments__form_erb__783297827544755550_70200180247600'
```

I understand that I might have to include a helper somewhere to have the tabs rendered, but I'm not sure about which one to use and where to include it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up entering the HTML manually, in the following way:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#consignment-details">Consignment Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#consignment-details">Trucks</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">

    <div id="consignment-details">
    </div>

    <div id="containers">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The same can be done using activeadmin syntax within `form do |f|; end` block

```
div(class: 'tabs') do
  ul(class: 'nav nav-tabs', role: 'tablist') do
    li { link_to 'Consignment Details', '#consignment-details' }
    li { link_to 'Containers', '#containers' }
  end
  div(class: 'tab-content') do

    div(id: 'consignment-details') do
      f.inputs do #your form goes here
      #...
      end
    end

    #second tab

  end
end
```