# Tabs' contents fails to hide at the beginning

Tags: tabs, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I will try to explain this problem so that it is understood perfectly for everyone. The thing is I'm displaying data and charts separated into several tabs using [this syntaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988429/how-to-use-tabs-in-an-activeadmin-edit-form-rendered-from-an-erb-partial).

In other words

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#consignment-details">Consignment Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#consignment-details">Trucks</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="consignment-details">
    </div>

    <div id="containers">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or

```
div(class: 'tabs') do
  ul(class: 'nav nav-tabs', role: 'tablist') do
    li { link_to 'Consignment Details', '#consignment-details' }
    li { link_to 'Containers', '#containers' }
  end

  div(class: 'tab-content') do
    div(id: 'consignment-details') do
    end

    div(id: 'containers') do
    end
  end
end
```

Although I like the way it looks, **I always notice how the content of all the tabs (and also the links) is seen at the beginning for a few tenths of a second**

[image]

**Is there a way to avoid this?**

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly known as FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content). This is basically because the CSS (or JS) that hides the inactive tabs is loaded when the DOM is completed.

This can usually be avoided by adding some CSS directly in the main template, like this:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Then you can add this class to your hidden elements, and they should be hidden from the very start. Any subsequent JS or CSS that then overrides the `display` property can easily hide/show the content as needed.

I don't use Active Admin, so I don't have any direct experience for this specific framework, but the above is a general understanding of the problem.

I hope this helps.